# Getting free range inside another range

Tags: bash, list

editing my question from the beginning since it was not clear enough:

Suppose you have a range from 1 to 1000.

Consider that some numbers in this range are reserved (this is dynamic).

E.g. 5, 45,670, 350. (i)

I want to get a 5-number continuous block of numbers inside range 1..1000, ensuring that this block of numbers does not include any reserved numbers. If this exists of course.

If (i) is the list of allocated numbers, the first block is 6,7,8,9,10. It can't be 1,2,3,4,5 because 5 is reserved.

I think it's more clear now :)

I think it should be a for loop examining all numbers from 1 to 995, and checking for each number whether start number is reserved - if not, examine if the 4 following numbers are also reserved. If not, we have a block. If yes, continue to the next unallocated number and check the 4 digits following up Again and again. When first free block is met, break the loop and store it!

Comment: A bit strange, could you try to improve explanation and give some sample code you have? At least an algorithm.

Comment: Consider how the numbers in use are specified — and state that in the question.  Are they specified in order?  Is there a more economical representation than N, M, O, … Z — a list of simple numbers?  Can a compressed representation of the used values make it easier to find gaps of a given size?  How often are you going to do this?  (Once: it doesn't matter what algorithm or representation you use.  Many times: it begins to matter, though with a range of only 1000 brute force will take you a long way.)

Comment: one free 5-sized block is enough ;). So the answer is once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
rs=(5 45 670 350)
for co in {1..1000}
do
  oa+=($co)
  for ec in ${rs[*]}
  do
    let co==ec && unset oa
  done
  let ${#oa[*]}==5 && break
done
echo ${oa[*]}
```